# php foreach - how to combine multiple urls

Tags: php, foreach

how do i combined these to only use one for each loop. its a pain to copy and paste new code for each additional url i want to add. plus its not very efficient.

```
$urlone = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/100404580017882/posts'));
$urltwo = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/100404590017836/posts'));

foreach($urlone->data as $post) { 
       echo $post->message, PHP_EOL . "<br>"; 
       if(++$counter >= 1) 
       { 
          break; 
       } 
    } 

foreach($urltwo->data as $post) { 
       echo $post->message, PHP_EOL . "<br>"; 
       if(++$counter >= 1) 
       { 
          break; 
       } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what functions were made for:

```
function echo_messages($url)
{
     $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
     foreach($data->data as $post) 
     { 
       echo $post->message, PHP_EOL . "<br>"; 
     } 
     //Wasn't sure what the counter was for, looks like it would just break after the first message was echoed.
}

echo_messages('https://graph.facebook.com/100404580017882/posts');
echo_messages('https://graph.facebook.com/100404590017836/posts');
```

By the way, if you are just trying to output the latest post, then doing it in a foreach loop and just breaking after the first one is the wrong way.  You should address it directly with something like `$variable->data[0]->message`.  Or, you could modify the code above to build in a settable limit to the max number of messages displayed like:

```
function echo_messages($url,$max = 1)
{
     $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
     $counter = 0;
     foreach($data->data as $post) 
     { 
       echo $post->message, PHP_EOL . "<br>";
       $counter++;
       if($counter >= $max)
       {
            return true;
       }
    } 
}

echo_messages('https://graph.facebook.com/100404580017882/posts',5); //Display last 5 posts from this one
echo_messages('https://graph.facebook.com/100404590017836/posts'); //Display last post from this one
```

Comment: Welcome.  And this is literally what functions were made for: to allow for easy multiple reuse of a block of code without having to repeat it.

Answer (score 0):

[`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array-merge) is your solution.

```
$urlone = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/100404580017882/posts'));
$urltwo = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/100404590017836/posts'));

$data = array_merge($urlone->data, $urltwo->data);

foreach($data as $post) { 
    echo $post->message, PHP_EOL . "<br>"; 
    if(++$counter >= 1) 
    { 
        break; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it inside a function is probably the way to go, since you can't guarantee that whatever it is returned will have the same length.

```
function fetch_posts($url){
  $obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
  foreach($obj->data as $post) { 
    echo $post->message, PHP_EOL . "<br>"; 
    if(++$counter >= 1) { 
      break; 
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create or obtain an array of the urls that you want to process in this fashion, then use a function on each item in the array:

```
$urls = array('https://graph.facebook.com/...', 'https://graph.facebook.com/....');

function printPosts($url){
    echo "<div class='posts'>";
    $posts = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

    foreach($posts->data as $post) { 
        echo $post->message, PHP_EOL . "<br>";
        //etc
    } 
    echo "</div>\n";
}
```